# regularizer causes "ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank"

Tags: keras

When trying to run

```py
import numpy as np
import keras

X = np.ones((100,20))
Y1 = np.ones((100,5))
Y2 = np.ones((100,4))

Input_1= keras.layers.Input(shape=X.shape[1])

x = keras.layers.Dense(100)(Input_1)
x = keras.layers.Dense(100)(x)

out1 = keras.layers.Dense(5, kernel_regularizer='l1')(x)
out2 = keras.layers.Dense(4)(x)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=Input_1, outputs=[out1,out2])
model.compile(loss = 'mse', loss_weights=np.arange(2))

model.fit(X, [Y1, Y2], epochs=2)
```

I get

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805
> train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795
> step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259
> run
> return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730
> call_for_each_replica
> return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417
> _call_for_each_replica
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788
> run_step  **
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756
> train_step
> y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:236
> **call**
> total_loss_metric_value = math_ops.add_n(loss_metric_values)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201
> wrapper
> return target(*args, **kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3572
> add_n
> return gen_math_ops.add_n(inputs, name=name)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:419
> add_n
> "AddN", inputs=inputs, name=name)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750
> _apply_op_helper
> attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:592
> _create_op_internal
> compute_device)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3536
> _create_op_internal
> op_def=op_def)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2016
> **init**
> control_input_ops, op_def)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1856
> _create_c_op
> raise ValueError(str(e))
>
> ```
> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
>   From merging shape 1 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=3, T=DT_FLOAT](mul_2, mul_5, dense_199/kernel/Regularizer/mul)' with input shapes: [2], [2], [].
> ```

The error disappears if I omit the regularizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [found](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) that `loss_weights` has to be a list, not an array.

```py
import numpy as np
import keras

X = np.ones((100,20))
Y1 = np.ones((100,5))
Y2 = np.ones((100,4))

Input_1= keras.layers.Input(shape=X.shape[1])

x = keras.layers.Dense(100)(Input_1)
x = keras.layers.Dense(100)(x)

out1 = keras.layers.Dense(5, kernel_regularizer='l1')(x)
out2 = keras.layers.Dense(4)(x)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=Input_1, outputs=[out1,out2])
model.compile(loss = 'mse', loss_weights=list(np.arange(2)))

model.fit(X, [Y1, Y2], epochs=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
changing the reduction of loss function from none to auto worked like a charm.

`tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO)`