# Keras: regularizer conflicts with loss_weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am building a network using the functional API of Keras to concatenate two networks. I also want to use the loss weights and regularization. I put an MWE below.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import L2

x1, x2 = np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 4)), np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 4))
y = np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 2))
loss_weights = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 2))

in1 = Input(shape=(4,))
d1 = Dense(100)(in1)
in2 = Input(shape=(4,))
d2 = Dense(100)(in2)
merge = concatenate([d1, d2])
d3 = Dense(2, bias_regularizer=L2(1e-4), kernel_regularizer=L2(1e-4))(d2)

model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=d3)
model.compile(loss='mse', loss_weights=loss_weights)
model.fit([x1, x2], y)
```

This leads to the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-24c2e74ecfe3> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit([x1, x2], y)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 890, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 949, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 238, in __call__
        total_loss_metric_value = tf.add_n(loss_metric_values)

    ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0
        From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT](mul_1, dense_2/kernel/Regularizer/mul)' with input shapes: [1000,2], [].
```

From a similar problem where I don't need the loss_weights, I found out that regularization really helps, so I don't want to omit it (the code above is running when omitting the regularizers). There is already a similar question: [regularizer causes "ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970626/regularizer-causes-valueerror-shapes-must-be-equal-rank), but both of the proposed solutions didn't work for me.

Any idea what could help?

Comment: I don't think [loss_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) is doing what you think it does. It's only useful if you have a multiple outputs, to weigh each contribution differently. You might be looking for the [sample_weights parameter of the fit method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) instead,

Comment: Yes, loss weights has nothing to do here, you do not have a multi output model.

Comment: I think you are right that loss_weights is not correct for. However, sample weights is also not correct because I want have several neurons in the output, and dependent of the sample some of them are irrelevant so I want the model to ignore them.